# How do I get a slice from a Postgres array in Golang?

Tags: sql, postgresql, go

Let's say I have a postgres query like:

```
SELECT
  id,
ARRAY_AGG(code) AS code
  FROM
    codes
WHERE id = '9252781' 
GROUP BY id;
```

My return looks like:

```
 id        |  codes
-----------+-------------
 9252781   | {H01,H02}
```

Both `id` and `codes` are `varchar`.

In Golang when I scan along the rows for my result, it just freezes. No error, nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using the `github.com/lib/pq` postgres driver you can use their [pq.Array](https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq#Array) helper function to scan and store postgres arrays.

```
var id string
var arr []string

row := db.QueryRow(`SELECT '9252781', ARRAY['H01','H02']`)
if err := row.Scan(&id, pq.Array(&arr)); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

log.Println(id, arr)
// 9252781 [H01 H02]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to use a additional driver (`github.com/lib/pq`), and I did not found any `pgx` way to do it other than creating my own type.

So I did one:

```golang
type Tags []string
func (t *Tags) Scan(v interface{}) error {
        if v == nil {
                *t = Tags{}
                return nil
        }
        s, ok := v.(string)
        if !ok {
                return fmt.Errorf("Scan is expected to receive a string from database, but got [%+v]", v)
        }
        s = strings.TrimPrefix(s, "{")
        s = strings.TrimSuffix(s, "}")
        *t = strings.Split(s, ",")
        return nil
}
func (t *Tags) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
        s := fmt.Sprintf("{%v}", strings.Join(([]string)(*t), ","))
        return s, nil
}
```

then you can scan the row returned from database like:

```golang
...
    err := rows.Scan(
        ...
        &Tags,
        ...
    )
```

and you can use it directly you your `Exec` queries.

This code works well with constants in arrays, but you need more work if want to use it in commas and brackets.